# How can I read the value of a given item in a tuple in a given row?

Tags: vb.net

I'm new to tuples in VB.Net, did a search here before posting this but could not find anything that could lead me to what I'm trying to do...

I have a public tuple that was declared as a list of two strings...

After populating the tuple, at a certain point, I want to check every row of the tuple and find if the value of the 2nd item of that given row is an empty string... I want to use a `For Loop` so I can use the `i` variable to loop through each row of the tuple...

So in the line `If MyTuple.(i.Item2) <> String.text Then`, the pseudocode would be something like this:

Get the tuple's `Item2` value for the row `i` and check if it is empty. Of course, the code above is garbage, I'm just trying to express what I'm after...

```
Public MyTuple As New List(Of Tuple(Of String, String))

MyTuple.Add(Tuple.Create("John", "Claire"))
MyTuple.Add(Tuple.Create("Dave", "Juan"))

For i As Integer = 0 To MyTuple.Count - 1

If MyTuple.(i.Item2) <> String.Empty Then

'Do something

End If

Next
```

Any ideas on how I could achieve that?

Thank you!

Comment: Perhaps it might be better to use a For Each loop rather than a Form with an index?

Comment: `If MyTuple(i).Item2 <> "Some String" Then ...` -- Note that you could also use a ValueTuple, in the form of `Public MyTuple As New List(Of (SomeName As String, OtherName As String))`, you can add items as `MyTuple.Add(("John", "Claire"))` and use the named elements as `If MyTuple(i).OtherName <> "Some String" Then ...`, but also as `If MyTuple(i).Item2 <> "Some String" Then ...`

Comment: I think you are confused on the language. The tuple is not the list. Instead of "every row in the Tuple", you say "every Tuple in the List".

Answer (score 0):

I went with @jimi suggestion and it worked.

`Public MyTuple As New List(Of (SomeName As String, OtherName As String))`

Closing. Thanks, everyone for the input.